# Find a pair of string at integer and subtract, java

Tags: java

I have a string which contains a value:

```
12345    5
54321    4
98765    10
```

The first value is a number, the second value is a count. The string value is obtained by this code:

```
for(ClusterListBean bean : clusterList) {
    line += bean.getMSISDN()+"\t"+bean.getRewardCount()+"\n";               
}
```

Now I am reading a file which has same contents but different count value.

This is accomplished by:

```
BufferedReader ln = FileCreatorUtil.readFile(configFileUtil.prevFile().getFileDir()+prevFile.clusterPrevFile().getFileName());
```

Now what I want to do is to search for a number value, get the count paired with it, and subtract the count. Example:

BufferedReader ln contents:

```
12345    5
54321    4
98765    10
```

String line contents:

```
12345    7
54321    9
98765    15
```

Output should be:

```
12345    2
54321    5
98765    5
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your data into a `HashMap` where MSISDN is key and count is value. Reading second file consult that map and subtract the value.

Comment: Alright thanks! I'll give it a try. I'll post the result here later.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put your "Strings" in a hashmap?

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for(ClusterListBean bean : clusterList) {
    map.put(bean.getMSISDN(),bean.getRewardCount());               
}
```

then read your file:

```
BufferedRead ln = null;
try{
    ln = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(configFileUtil.prevFile().getFileDir()+prevFile.clusterPrevFile().getFileName()));
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        String[] linesplit = line.split("\\t");
        if (map.containsKey(linesplit[0])){
             //do whatever you need with something like:
             System.out.println(map.get(linesplit[0])-Integer.parseInt(linesplit[1]));
        }
    }
    ln.close();
}catch(IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is what in trying to do exactly. I'll keep you posted.